# which coordinates use with mongodb geo queries using coordinates from google maps?

Tags: mongodb

I am storing in mongoDB coordinates simillar to google maps coordinates - for example 20.2345,34.2034. What I need is to get all documents within some search radius (in meters). But I am confused if I should use `2dsphere` index and `$nearSphere` query or `2d` index and `$near` query???

---

Ok I checked it and using `2d` index both `$near` and `$nearSphere` queries return strange results. Using `2dsphere` index returned correct results using both `$near` and `$nearSphere` queries. I checked 2 points with distance between them = ~3800m. Then I was looking for a treshold radius which will include the second point (assuming where are looking from first point). Here are results:

1. index: '2d', $near -> radius = ~57
2. index: '2d', $nearSphere -> radius = 0.99
3. index: '2dsphere', $near -> radius = ~3850
4. index: '2dsphere', $nearSphere -> radius = ~3850

I have no idea whats going on with `2d` index - I always used `$geometry: { type: 'Point' ...` to always use meters not radians...

Any way just use `2dsphere` index and it will be fine. I also had to drop collection to reindex from '2d' to '2dsphere' (db.collection.reIndex() didnt work)

Answer (score 1):

To more closely reflect that the Earth is a sphere, you want the `2dsphere` index as described here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/

I'm not entirely sure of the difference between `$near` and `$nearSphere` on a `2dsphere` index but I get the impression that either will work. It looks like `$nearSphere` allows you to specify distance in radians not just meters.

Comment: But what will be the difference between this two options I metioned in my question when I will use same coordinate values?

Comment: Based on your edit and output, I'm not sure why the `2d` index finding the second document with a much smaller radius. Perhaps if you pasted the query strings? In any case, I think your analysis is correct. Use `2dsphere` unless there's an explicit reason you need to have a `2d` index.